# str_replace does not replace all the keys?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm making my own forum software. 
Well its normal to have smileys in your forum.

So i made an array with all the smileys and putted them in a function:

```
function si_ubb($string){
    $smileys = array(
        '0<:)' => 'angelnot.gif',
        '>:(' => 'angry.gif',
        ':@' => 'blush.gif',
        ':*' => 'cencored.png',
        ':?' => 'confused.gif',
        ';(' => 'cry.png',
        ':D' => 'grin.gif',
        ':)' => 'happy.gif',
        ':|' => 'hmm.png',
        '0:)' => 'hypocrite.gif',
        ':x:' => 'lock.gif',
        '<3' => 'love.gif',
        '8)' => 'rolleyes.gif',
        ':(' => 'sad.png',
        '|)' => 'shifty.gif',
        'O_o' => 'shock.gif',
        '8)' => 'sunglasses.gif',
        '^_^' => 'sweatingbullets.gif',
        ':p' => 'tongue.gif',
        ':P' => 'tongue.gif',
        ';)' => 'wink.gif',
        '>.<' => 'wry.gif',
        'XD' => 'wry.gif',
        'xD' => 'wry.gif'
    );

    foreach($smileys as $code => $image){
        $string = str_replace($code, $image, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

But, ehm, when i do this now:

`echo si_ubb('0<:)');`

It gives this?

0<[image]

But how? And why?
Why isn't it showing the right smiley?

Greetings

Comment: It seems that it is replacing `':)' => 'happy.gif'` before `'0<:)' => 'angelnot.gif'`.

Comment: I get the correct result. My guess is the array index is getting screwed up by the leading `0` for some reason. Can you try a `print_r($smileys);`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the response you're getting? I just ran your code and it returned "angelnot.gif". What version of php are you using?

Comment: You should show the complete code. This snippet only substitutes emoticons for filenames and does not provide the <img> tags. So the actual problem might lurk elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry i was away for a few minutes, but how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ck3g said, move `':)' => 'happy.gif',` below `'0:)' => 'hypocrite.gif',`

Answer (score 1):

```
':)' => 'happy.gif'
```

You have already on case. Your `0<:)` is part of `:)`. After first replacement you get `0<happy.gif`

You'll get same issue with `':(' => 'sad.png'`

Comment: I think that the problem is something different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Like Michiel said. It does a 'non-greedy' replace. You might want to read up on greedy-regexp's  (@see preg_replace)

Comment: Im not familliar with the preg expression.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you should have values which contain other values in the same array appearing first.

Eg 0:) before :)

This can affect the sort of replacement even when you use preg_replace without the proper greedy modifier.

On the redundancy of the foreach loop, I am not sure but you could try array_keys() and array_values() as the parameters and see(I use something similar with preg_replace. I have never tried with str_replace().)

Str_replace(array_keys($codes), array_values($codes), $string);

However, why don't you take a look at pears bbcode_parser or even the bbcode module or http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/php/bbcode/index_en.html

You might need them to extend your tags. These are all stack based parsers that ensure proper nesting and even parse nested quote tags properly.

For an independent script, use the last example. Easily extendable with no dependencies.